# reload datepicker dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datepicker, clone

ok i have a javascript object to control elements on my page such as load html, undo, redo etc.

When i do undo, it removes the datepickers from the inputs that should be datepickers.

My code is located here: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/qAWuA/

i changed my code to inline JSON just for the fiddle

It has 6 columns, two of them being datepickers with start date and its expiration.

When a user clicks of undo or undo all -- the datepickers no longer work.

Can someone please help me out here?

Thanks :-D

**UPDATED**

still have the issue, but i changed the fiddle a bit

Comment: This has to do with using the `clone` function without the `withDataAndEvents` argument set to true. However, even setting that property to true doesn't solve your issue. You might be safer refactoring your datepicker initialization code into a separate function that is run after you perform the undo.

Comment: @Andrew -- how though? there can be many many lines that need to be redone. can you show me in a fiddle?

Comment: You're just calling `$('#page').remove();` which will kill all the event handlers.  At first I thought just adding $('input.hasDatepicker').datepicker(); in your undo method would help, but apparently not.  jsfiddle is having some latency problems so I can't continue my debugging, but good luck.  You must be further killing your event handlers somehow. (EDIT: looks like @Andrew has the same idea)

Comment: @Milimetric, if you can would u be able to try to make it work? i have already worked on this for a few hours to no avail, maybe new brains might be able to help....

Comment: If jsfiddle starts behaving itself I will try :)  Take a break, that usually helps :)

Comment: @Milimetric when jsfiddle starts misbehaving for me i clear the browser cache, that sometimes work for me ^_^

Comment: @milimetric, is there any update to how u can help at all?

Comment: @milimetric, your right, i needed a clear head and i solved the issue (a bit hacky, but thats the best i could do right now), if you have a better solution, please let me know :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue:

i added this line to both of the undo clicks:

```
self.refreshDatePickers();
```

on create row i added this to expiration:

```
case 'expiration':
     td.append($('<input>',
          {value: i, name: index+"["+topIndex+"]", 
               type: 'text', size: 30, id: 'to['+topIndex+']', 
               'class': 'dp', 'index': topIndex}));
     break;
```

and then i added the `refreshDatePickers` function:

```
refreshDatePickers: function(){
    var self = this;
    $.each($('.dp'),function(){
        var index = $(this).attr('index');
        var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
        $( "input[name='startDate["+index+"]'], input[name='expiration["+index+"]']", tr ).removeClass("hasDatepicker");
        self.createDatePicker(index, tr);
    })
}
```